# Exclude a page from session timeout in web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, session-timeout, web.xml

I'm just wondering, is it possible to exclude a page (say, the login.jsp) from session timeout in web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The session is for everything. But `login.jsp` does not need a session. It should assume that no user is logged, hence no previous session exists.